# Do i need to make some payment on my free-tier AWS account? What should i do now?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, billing

[image]

I received this mail now and I am using a free-tier account of AWS. This is for the first time that I got an email from them regarding my usage and I don't know what to do in response to this. Do I need to take some actions on my AWS account? Please help me I am new to AWS.

[image]
I also got to know that I have been billed $0.59 on this account. So do I need to do some payment or is it fine?

Comment: Please note that there is no such thing as a "free-tier account". Rather, the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a **billing discount**. If you only use services within the free tier, then your account will not be charged. Anything outside of the free tier will be charged as normal (because it is a normal AWS Account).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you used a feature from Route 53 that is not part of the free tier. It is not a fine, it is a service charge and needs to be paid. If you have your credit card on file, it will automatically be deducted. To ensure not to incur any more costs, have a look at the services and features that are part of the free tier [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), and turn off everything else.

To prevent this in the future you can set up a [budget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html) which will send you a warning when your service charges are going beyond a predefined amount.

Comment: I am using route 53 for DNS  purpose and i have no idea if i stop using this then what is the alternative of ROUTE 53  for free of charge. How can i request and address DNS server on my site?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pay this.

With AWS the free tier covers a select number of services, some of these last 12 months from the opening of the account whereas others have a free tier forever (such as Lambda with 1,000,000 free invocations per month).

You're being billed for Route 53 which does not have a free tier.

The complete list of free tier is available from [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Comment: So what do i need to use instead of route 53 to get free tier and and not get billed for the same? Is there any service in free tier that does the same stuff of route 53 and can replace it? Please help me i am not a tech guy. I am very new to all these fields

Comment: I understand, if you're using AWS for your public DNS you have to use Route 53 (no free tier alternative). You would need to find another service by a third party that can host DNS for free.

Comment: Hosting DNS by third party.. is it safe like aws?

Comment: It depends on how reputable they are, there are many providers out there but many will charge a great deal more than AWS. Make sure to invest in reading up before taking the decision :)

Comment: Thank you for your support Chris. I have decided and my mind to host my site on AWS but do i need to worry about any security purpose cause i listened someone saying that aws manages all your website security and almost there is no chance of getting hacked. i am afraid of being hacked cause my other site hosted on siteground recently got hacked and hacker hosted some malwares on my site

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a **courtesy email** saying that you have exceeded 85% of a free tier limit for an AWS Free Tier-eligible service. Specifically, you have used 643 hours of Load Balancer usage out of a limit of 750 hours (`643/750=85.7%`).

It is not a bill. Is simply letting you know about your usage, because your total consumption for the month *might* exceed 100% of the Free Tier for that service.

That email is totally separate to the charge for Route 53 that you have incurred.

Comment: So what can i do to not exceed my free-tier limit of my Load Balancer ?

Comment: is this mean that if i want to go totally free of cost i need to stop using Route 53? if yes, then what can replace route 53 for free service?

Comment: Please note that the AWS Free Tier is designed to provide users with the opportunity to gain experience in using certain AWS services. It is _not_ intended for production usage. There is no free usage tier for Amazon Route 53. If you feel that a charge of $0.50/month for a hosted zone is beyond your budget, you could consider using other services. Similarly, 750 hours per month of a Load Balancer is sufficient to run a load balancer continuously for the whole month (or two load balancers for a half month) _for the first 12 months of your account_.

Comment: So did it mean that i need to pay $0.50 each month for using route 53 and need not to worry about my 85% usage limit as there is only few days left in ending of this month? FYI i am using only one Load Balancer on my site. Can't i go for one-time payment for route 53 annually?

Comment: AWS is an on-demand service. You will be charged for the services you use during the month. There are some services that provide pre-paid options (eg Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances), but Amazon Route 53 is not one of those services.